# Implicit Derivative of $2xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'd always thought it was solved like this:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(2xy)=0=\frac{d}{dx}(x\cdot2y)= 2y$$
as $\frac{d}{dx}(kx) = k$

However according to multiple online differentiators, the actual answer is:

$$2xy′+ 2y =0$$

-- I realized the product rule - $$\frac{d}{dx}(ab) =  a\cdot b′ + a′ \cdot b $$ - gives the results from the websites but why doesn't the rule $$\frac{d}{dx}(kx) = k$$ apply?

Comment: $y$ isn't a constant, $y = y(x)$. Also, when differentiating $kx$ with $k$ a constant, you **do** use the product rule, it's just that $$\frac{d}{dx} k = 0$$ so one of the terms vanishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $y$ depends also of $x$, $y=y(x)$ so you have the product rule.

$x'=1$ and $y(x)'=y'$.

The rule that you said it is only valid if $y(x)$ were constant.

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(2xy) 
&= 2 \left(\frac{d}{dx} (xy) \right) \\
&= 2 \left( \left(\frac{d}{dx} x \right)y + x \frac{d}{dx} y \right) \\
&= 2 (y + x y') \quad (*)
\end{align}
due to the rule for constants and the product rule.

This also applies for $x$ and $k$:
$$
(xk)' = k + x k'
$$
Only for $k' = 0$, in other words: $k$ is constant regarding $x$, this leads to $(xk)' = k$.

Because $y$ might not be constant regarding $x$, equation $(*)$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}{x}} (2xy) = 0$$

Here are few things you need to remember:

1. $x$ is a *variable* and not a constant.
2. $y$ is a function of $x$ i.e. $y(x)$

The rule that you mentioned only works if you are multiplying a *variable* to a *constant*. In this case, you are multiplying a *variable* to a *function*.

So, that means you need to use the product rule

> $$x \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}{x}} y + \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}{x}} x \cdot y$$

Now, what is the derivative of $y$? This is $y'$. What is the derivative of $x$? It is $1$. So, we have:

$$2(xy' + y) = 0$$

Let me know if you have further questions